# WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringLoginApplication/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringLoginApplication'

Tags: java, spring

My project is a maven project when i run the project on tomcat it shows 
**org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringLoginApplication/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringLoginApplication'**

I tried all possibilities to resolve but all in vein, can somebody help me out to resolve this issue

**my controller :**

```
    package com.spring.login.controller;

        import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
        import javax.validation.Valid;

        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
        import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
        import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

        import com.spring.login.beans.Customer;
        import com.spring.login.services.CustomerService;
        import com.spring.login.validation.CustomerValidation;

        @Controller 
        public class CustomerController {

        @Autowired
        private CustomerService customerService;

        @RequestMapping(value="/" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String login(ModelMap model){
        //model.put("Info", new Customer());
        return "/login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(ModelMap model){
    model.put("customerData", new Customer());
    return "/register";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value= "/register", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveForm(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("customerData") @Valid Customer customer, BindingResult br, HttpSession session){
    CustomerValidation customerValidation = new CustomerValidation();
    customerValidation.validate(customerValidation, br);
    if(br.hasErrors()){
    return "/register";
    }
    else{
        customerService.saveCustomer(customer);
        session.setAttribute("customer", customer);
        return "redirect:success";
        }
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logOut(ModelMap model, HttpSession session){

        session.removeAttribute("customer");
        return "redirect:login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/success", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logOut(ModelMap model){

        model.put("customer", new Customer());
        return "redirect:success";
}

}
```

**my web.xml :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" >
    <display-name>SpringLoginApplication</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>


   org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-
    class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringLoginApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-
     class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/SpringLoginApplication-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>

   org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringLoginApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    </web-app>
```

**my SpringLoginApplication-servlet.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

 xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.login.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.login.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.login.beans" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.login.services" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.login.validation" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config />

<bean 
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
<bean class="com.spring.login.beans.Customer" init-method="getC_id" destroy-
method="getC_name">
    <property name="c_id" value="1234"/>
    <property name="c_name" value="Sanjay"/>
</bean>


</beans>
```

A working response would be highly appreciated!

**ANY OTHER INFO REQUIRED, PLS LET ME KNOW**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem few days before, and I got bellow solution.

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping(value="/" )
public class CustomerController {

//do your stuff here
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(ModelMap model){
    //model.put("Info", new Customer());
    return "/login";
}

//Rest of your stuff goes here
```

}

Since you have configured your Dispatcher servlet to handle your context in stead of all possibility which people generally do by adding this (/*), so above provided code snippet will work and redirect your context to /login which you want(if i'm not wrong). Cheers!!!!